# How to properly evaluate this expression of a Wiener integral $E\left[ \exp \left( \int_0^t f(s)dB_s \right)^2 \right]$?

Tags: solution-verification, stochastic-calculus

Given $f \in L^2$, I am trying to simplify the following expression

$$E\left[  \exp \left( \int_0^t f(s)dB_s \right)^2 \right]$$

What I know is that $\int_0^t f(s)dB_s$ is a Wiener integral, so it has a Gaussian distribution of zero mean and variance $\int_0^t f(s)^2ds$.  I am getting out of my comfort zone but here it goes.

$\int_0^t f(s)dB_s$ is Gaussian, so $\exp \left( \int_0^t f(s)dB_s \right)$ is log-normal. Let $\exp \left( \int_0^t f(s)dB_s \right)=Y_t$, so then $E[Y_t^2]$ is the second moment of the log-normal random variable. Using the moment generating function $E[X^n]=\exp(n\mu + n^2 \sigma^2/2)$ we have
$$E[Y_t^2]=\exp\left(2\int_0^t f(s)^2ds \right)$$

The importance of this is that I would like it to be finite, which it is (if this derivation is correct) since $f \in L^2$. How does this look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $ \int_0^t f(s)dB_s \sim N(0;\int_0^t f^2(s)ds)$.

Let's denote $a =\int_0^t f^2(s)ds$, then it suffices to calculate $E(e^{aX^2})$ with $X \sim N(0,1)$.

And $E(e^{aX^2})$ [exists if and only if](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20%28exp%28a*t%5E2%29*exp%28-t%5E2%2F2%29%2Fsqrt%282*pi%29%29%20from%20-infinity%20to%20infinity%20%20with%20a%3C0.5) $a<\frac{1}{2}$. If this condition is satisfied, then $E(e^{aX^2}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2a}}$

Conclusion: if  $\int_0^t f^2(s)ds < \frac{1}{2}$ then
$$E\left[  \exp \left( \int_0^t f(s)dB_s \right)^2 \right] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2\int_0^t f^2(s)ds}}$$

**PS:** the expectation $E\left[ \left( \exp \left( \int_0^t f(s)dB_s \right)\right)^2 \right]$ can be calculated as follows

\begin{align}
E\left[ \left( \exp \left( \int_0^t f(s)dB_s \right)\right)^2 \right] &= E\left[  \exp \left( 2\int_0^t f(s)dB_s \right) \right] \\
&= E\left[  \exp \left( 2\sqrt{\int_0^t f^2(s)ds} *X \right) \right] \\
\end{align}
We know that $E[e^{aX}] = e^{\frac{a^2}{2}}$, then
$$E\left[ \left( \exp \left( \int_0^t f(s)dB_s \right)\right)^2 \right] = \exp \left( 2\int_0^t f^2(s)ds \right)$$

Comment: I'm sorry shouldn't we be considering $E[(e^{aX})^2]$ and not $E[(e^{aX^2})]$?

Comment: Maybe my notation isn't correct, The part inside the expected value could be written like this with another set of parentheses $E[\left( \exp \left( \int_0^t f(s) dBs \right) \right)^2 ]$. I need to square the exponential function, not take an exponential of the square.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind The expectation $E\left[  \exp \left( \int_0^t f(s)dB_s \right)^2 \right]$ can be calculated easier (remind that $(e^y)^2 = e^{2y}$). I modified the answer for this expectation.